# Flutter Shared preferences returns null on first run after install

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app where I save user details in a shared preferences file on user login, after login is done, user is navigated to homepage. When I freshly install the app on an emulator or physical device, on the homepage, the shared preferences return as null when assigned to a text widget but as soon as I press the "hot restart" button, everything functions normally... Please help.

here the code of my homepage below

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _name, _userID;
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getSP();
  }

  getSP() async {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((SharedPreferences sp) {
      sharedPreferences = sp;
      _name = sharedPreferences.getString("name");
      _userID = sharedPreferences.getString("uid");
      // will be null if never previously saved
      
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/back2.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/rlogo.png",
                    height: 50,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10, 30),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        _name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontFamily: "Muli",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: kPrimaryColor),
                      ),
```

here is where i saved the data to shared preferences

```
Future readData(FirebaseUser fUser) async {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(fUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then((dataSnapshot) {
      RitechApp.sharedPreferences
          .setString("uid", dataSnapshot.data[RitechApp.userUID]);

      RitechApp.sharedPreferences.setString(
          RitechApp.userEmail, dataSnapshot.data[RitechApp.userEmail]);

      RitechApp.sharedPreferences
          .setString(RitechApp.phoneNumber, dataSnapshot.data["phoneNumber"]);

      RitechApp.sharedPreferences
          .setString(RitechApp.userName, dataSnapshot.data[RitechApp.userName]);
    });
  }

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  void loginUser() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) {
          return LoadingAlertDialog(
            message: "Authenticating, Please wait.....",
          );
        });
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    await _auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
      password: _passwordTextEditingController.text.trim(),
    )
        .then((authUser) {
      firebaseUser = authUser.user;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) {
            return ErrorAlertDialog(
              message: error.message.toString(),
            );
          });
    });

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      readData(firebaseUser).then((s) {
        Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c) => MainScreen());
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please, post your code

Comment: I've posted the code